# Connecting a Google Cloud Storage bucket to a Docker image in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, persistence

I've created an app on GAE in the flexible environment, running a custom run-time with a docker image of Jenkins 2 ([source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/jenkins-docker/blob/master/2/README.md)) from Google Cloud Launcher ([launcher](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/details/google/jenkins2?project=stepex-jenkins&folder&organizationId)).

In the readme file on GitHub, the instructions are clear for a Google Compute Engine customer, however on the App Engine, all volumes are ephemeral (I believe).

> Adding persistence
>
> All Jenkins data lives in /var/jenkins_home, including plugins and configurations. This directory should be mounted on a persistent volume to survive container restarts.
>
> Assume /path/to/jenkins/home is the persistent directory on your host.
>
> Add the following content to the docker-compose.yml file, then run docker-compose up.
>
> ```
> volumes:
>   - /path/to/jenkins/home:/var/jenkins_home
> ```

My question is then, given that app engine autocreates a Cloud Storage bucket at <\PROJECT-ID>.appspot.com, is there a simple way to mount this, or even better, is there a simple way to modify the configuration of Dockerfile, or app.yaml, such that /var/jenkins is persistent?